# BOOST Regex global Search behavior

Tags: c++, regex, perl, boost

My question is about whether the boost regex engine can do "global searches".
I've tried and I can't get it to do it.

The match_results class contains the base pointer of the string, so after incrementing the
starting position manually then setting the `match_flag_type` to `match_not_bob | match_prev_avail`,
I would have thought the boost regex engine would be able to know it is in the middle of a string.

Since I'm using this engine in my software, I'd like to know if this engine can infact do this correctly and I'm doing something wrong, or global searching is not possible with this engine.

Below are sample code/output using BOOST regex, and an equivalent Perl script.

*Edit:* Just to clarify, in the below boost example the `Start` iterator is always treated as a boundry. The engine doesn't seem to consider text to the left of that position when making a match.
At least in this case.

7/22/2014 -  **The Solution for Global Search**

Posting this update as the solution. Its not a workaround or kludge.
After googling '*regex_iterator*' I knew that regex_iterator sees the text to the left of the
current search position. And, I came across all the same source code. One site (like the others)
had an passing simple explanation of how it works that said it calls '*regex_search()*'
when the regex_iterator is incremented.

So down in the bowels of the regex_iterator class, I saw that it indeed called regex_search() when
the iterator was incremented ->Next().

This 'regex_search()' overload wasn't documented and comes in only 1 type.
It includes a BIDI parameter at the end named 'base'.

```
bool regex_search(BidiIterator first, BidiIterator last, 
                  match_results<BidiIterator, Allocator>& m, 
                  const basic_regex<charT, traits>& e, 
                  match_flag_type flags,
                  BidiIterator base)
{
   if(e.flags() & regex_constants::failbit)
      return false;

   re_detail::perl_matcher<BidiIterator, Allocator, traits> matcher(first, last, m, e, flags, base);
   return matcher.find();
}
```

It appears the base is the wall to the left of the start BIDI from where initial lookbehind's could use to check conditions..

So, I tested it out and it seemed to work.
The bottom line is to set base BIDI to the start of the input, and put the start BIDI anywhere after.
Effectively, this is like setting the pos() variable in Perl.

And, to emulate global positional increment on a zero-length match, a simple conditional is all that's
needed:

`Start = ( _M[0].length() == 0) ? _M[0].first + 1 : _M[0].second;` (see below)

**BOOST Regex 1.54  regex_search() using 'base' BIDI**
Note - in this example, Start always = _M[0].second;
The regex is purposely unlike the two other examples (below it), to demonstrate in fact
the text from  '*Base*' to '*Start*' is considered each time when matching this regex.

```
#typedef std::string::const_iterator SITR;

boost::regex Rx( "(?<=(.)).", regex_constants::perl );
regex_constants::match_flag_type Flags = match_default;

string str("0123456789");

SITR Start = str.begin();
SITR End   = str.end();
SITR Base  = Start;
boost::smatch _M;

while ( boost::regex_search( Start, End, _M, Rx, Flags, Base) )
{
    string str1(_M[1].first, _M[1].second );
    string str0(_M[0].first, _M[0].second );
    cout << str1 << str0 << endl;

    // This line implements the Perl global match flag m//g ->
    Start = ( _M[0].length() == 0) ? _M[0].first + 1 : _M[0].second;
}

output:
01
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
```

**Perl 5.10**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "0123456789";
while ( $str =~ /(?<=(..))/g )
{
    print ("$1\n");
}

output:**
01
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
```

**BOOST Regex 1.54  regex_search() no 'base'**

```
string str("0123456789");
std::string::const_iterator Start = str.begin();
std::string::const_iterator End = str.end();
boost::regex Rx("(?<=(..))", regex_constants::perl);
regex_constants::match_flag_type Flags = match_default;
boost::smatch _M;  

while ( boost::regex_search( Start, End, _M, Rx, Flags) )
{
    string str(_M[1].first, _M[1].second );
    cout << str << "\n";
    Flags |= regex_constants::match_prev_avail;
    Flags |= regex_constants::match_not_bob;
    Start = _M[0].second;
}

output:
01
23
45
67
89
```

Comment: regex_iterator<>::second should hold the last position of the match in the interval [begin, end). Have you tried starting from M[0].first + 1 instead?

Comment: @HomeroC.deAlmeida - Thanks for the reply. I know the start position could be manually set. The regex is not fixed to any one thing. So, the general behavior must come from the engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** in response to the comments **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcf22abe99d2929a)**:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    std::string str("0123456789");
    std::string::const_iterator start = str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();
    boost::regex re("(?<=(..))", regex_constants::perl);

    regex_constants::match_flag_type flags = match_default;
    boost::smatch match;  

    while (start<end && 
           boost::regex_search(start, end, match, re, flags))
    {
        std::cout << match[1] << "\n";

        start += 1; // NOTE

        //// some smartness that should work for most cases:
        // start = (match.length(0)? match[0] : match.prefix()).first + 1;

        flags |= regex_constants::match_prev_avail;
        flags |= regex_constants::match_not_bob;

        std::cout << "at '" << std::string(start,end) << "'\n";

    }
}
```

Prints:

```
01  at '123456789'
12  at '23456789'
23  at '3456789'
34  at '456789'
45  at '56789'
56  at '6789'
67  at '789'
78  at '89'
89  at '9'
```

Comment: Thanks @sehe. This is a good simulation. Unfortunately it can't be generalized with user entered regex's. Something like this `Start = (_M[0].length() == 0) ? _M[0].first + 1 : _M[0].second;` breaks using the regex `(?<=.).` Even `(?=.)` sends it into an infinite loop using `Start = _M[0].second;` I could write workarounds in that case, but the inability to see text at locations < Start makes it crippled.

Comment: Ah. Now I get the true gist of your question. Sadly, I think you're missing the bigger picture: accepting user input as regexes is a huge security no-no anyways. You will want to do validation or restrict the subset of regex constructs that is available (something without lookahead/behind would be nice here)

Comment: Really its just commercial software embedding boost regex as a single step find/replace utility. Its fully protected with exception handling. I know this engine like the back of my hand, its just this one thing that got me.

Comment: Oh well. It's just this one thing you hit :) I can probably craft some regexen that will send your PC into a coma - potentially losing work. But, you know, if "it's just commercial software", then it's not important, I suppose.

Comment: **Update** I've looked at your profile link and it would appear to me that you know what I'm talking about. Well then. You could try to get fancy and detect zero-width matches like `start = (match.length(0)? match[0] : match.prefix()).first + 1;`. But honestly, the only thing I see working generically is just `start += 1`, but that could be costly for performance in simple cases.

Comment: I use the engine extensively in other parts of the program and have a few sub-expression workarounds I have to use. The engine is very conservative. Usually if there is a potential catastrophic backtrack potential, it throws a too complex type exception. Don't do this yet on user entered regex, but its always possible to create a worker thread to execute the search, then use an interval timer that kicks off after 10 seconds that pops a dialog with the option to kill the thread. Something like that. About the `match.prefix()` I know its there, but where to start right?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. As far as I know `regex_search` can't  do a global search. But, I did kind of find out `regex_iterator` kind of does this. Thanks for your help/sugg's.